# Best Carbonation amount of sugar

Tags: carbonation, bottle-conditioning, priming-sugar

I am korean homebrewer. I brewed Citra Pale Ale, but I am not quite satisfied. After fermentation, I added 3g or 6g of priming sugar in 500ml bottles. The 3g of sugar bottles had good flavor but less carbonation. The 6g of sugar bottles had less flavor and were a little bit sweet, and they had more carbonation than the 3g but it is still not enough.

How do you carbonate(How long)?
How much do you priming the sugar?
Is it better use refined Dextrose?

Comment: how long did you let it sit in the bottles before testing carbonation?
Sugar type should not really matter, I use table sugar, others use dextrose...etc

Answer (score 1):

How long it will need depends mainly on temperature, and viability of the yeast. Viability of yeast in turn depends on things like strength of beer, length of primary (and secondary if applicable) fermentation, whether beer has been cold-crashed or had finings added to it prior to bottling.

I would say if it's a been a normal healthy fermentation of an average strength (5%) beer, you should bottle your beer and then wait at least one week at 20°C, two if preferable.

I normally use table (cane) sugar and that works fine. How much sugar to use depends on the style of beer. There are many online calculators to help you work this out - e.g. https://www.brewersfriend.com/beer-priming-calculator/

Comment: Do you mean wait at least one week at 20c on the first fermentation? or after bottling?

Comment: Sorry, edited my answer in case unclear

Comment: Thank you so much. I'ii brew same recipe of beer again.

Comment: If you still have bottles of beer that aren't properly carbonated you can always add some more sugar and re-cap them

Comment: ^ not a very good idea, too much effort and risks. Btw, I'm also using table sugar (sucrose) and noticed that 1 week is usually not enough to properly carbonate - 2 weeks is better.